# Yum update fails with connection refused on repo

Tags: fedora, raspberry-pi, yum

I have recently installed pidora on my Raspberry Pi B+, I have installed no programs, done nothing to any configuration and have tried to run yum update and it has failed.

I have tried a few fixes suggested on different forums such as `yum clean` and none work.

It is not a DNS error as I can ping the hostname (pidora.proximity.on.ca) and also other websites from the Pi.

Below is my verbose logging of yum update.
Any ideas would be much appreciated.

```
[mike@pidora /]$ sudo yum -v update
Not loading "blacklist" plugin, as it is disabled
Loading "langpacks" plugin
Loading "refresh-packagekit" plugin
Not loading "whiteout" plugin, as it is disabled
Adding en to language list
Config time: 0.419
Yum version: 3.4.3
rpmdb time: 0.003
Updating Everything
Building updates object
Setting up Package Sacks
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://pidora.proximity.on.ca/mirrorlist/mirrorlist.cgi?repo=pidora-20&arch=arm error was
14: curl#7 - "Failed connect to pidora.proximity.on.ca:80; Connection refused"
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://pidora.proximity.on.ca/mirrorlist/mirrorlist.cgi?repo=pidora-rpfr-updates-20&arch=arm error was
14: curl#7 - "Failed connect to pidora.proximity.on.ca:80; Connection refused"


 One of the configured repositories failed (pidora 20 - arm),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
        just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
        --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable pidora-rpfr-updates

     4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=pidora-rpfr-updates.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: pidora-rpfr-updates/20/arm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much fiddling, I tried a different repo hostname and now yum works. The steps for fixing are as follows.

1. Disable all repos in /etc/yum.repos.d/
2. In /etc/yum.conf add the following repo url' at the bottom.

   http://pidora.ca/pidora/updates/20/armv6hl/

   http://japan.proximity.on.ca/kojifiles/repos/f20-build/latest/armv6hl/